# changing div structure for an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I have an HTML structure in an array. However, I am not sure how to change each div structure according to my if condition, right now I am recreating four divs, but I wanted to change only one div. Is there a simpler way, like changing the first div content alone? Here is a  The relevant parts are below.

```
  var firstDay = "dayOne"
  if(firstDay){

    this.state = {
        'panes' : [

            <div className="sports-tab-content">
                <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">
                  day one First
                </p>
            </div>,

            <div className="sports-tab-content">
                <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">
                  light 
                </p>
            </div>,

            <div className="sports-tab-content">
                <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2 ft-day3">
                    bulb
                </p>
            </div>,

            <div className="sports-tab-content">
                <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2 ft-day3 ft-day4">
                  sky
                </p>
            </div>
        ]

    }
  }

  else {

    this.state = {
        'panes' : [

            <div className="sports-tab-content">
                <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">
                  day one inside else
                </p>
            </div>,

            <div className="sports-tab-content">
                <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">
                  jump

                </p>
            </div>,

            <div className="sports-tab-content">
                <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2 ft-day3">
                    drive 
                </p>
            </div>,

            <div className="sports-tab-content">
                <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2 ft-day3 ft-day4">
                  brush
                </p>
            </div>
        ]

    }
```

Comment: What's your problem? Hard to tell it from your problem description.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like the abstraction between display and state a bit odd. I would imagine storing properties that indicate which components or how components should render in the state would make it easier to accomplish what you are looking to do.

Instead of:

```
this.state = {
  panes : [
    <div className="sports-tab-content">
      <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">
        day one inside else
      </p>
    </div>,
    <div className="sports-tab-content">
      <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">
        day one First
      </p>
    </div>,
    <div className="sports-tab-content">
      <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2 ft-day3">
        day one First 
      </p>
    </div>,
    <div className="sports-tab-content">
      <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2 ft-day3 ft-day4">
        day one First 
      </p>
    </div>,
  ],
};
```

Possibly use:

```
this.state = {
  panes : [{
    classes: ['ft-day1', 'ft-day2'],
    text: 'day one inside else',
  }, {
    classes: ['ft-day1', 'ft-day2'],
    text: 'day one First',
  }, {
    classes: ['ft-day1', 'ft-day2', 'ft-day3'],
    text: 'day one First',
  }, {
    classes: ['ft-day1', 'ft-day2', 'ft-day3', 'ft-day4'],
    text: 'day one First',
  }],
};

render() {
  return (
    <Tabs selected={0} changeContent={this.changeContent}>
      <Pane label="Account Setup" subtitle="Days 1 and 2" liClass="sports-setup-ico first-time-active ft-active-tab">
        <PaneContent {...this.state.panes[0]} />
      </Pane>
      <Pane label="Investments Purchase" subtitle="Approx. Day 3" liClass="sports-invest-ico">
        <PaneContent {...this.state.panes[1]} />  
      </Pane>
      <Pane label="Balance and Portfolio" subtitle="Approx. Day 4" liClass="sports-balance-ico">
        <PaneContent {...this.state.panes[2]} />                  
      </Pane>
      <Pane label="IPerformance" subtitle="Approx. Day 5" liClass="sports-perf-ico">
        <PaneContent {...this.state.panes[3]} />
      </Pane>
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

PanelContent component being:

```
const PanelContent = (props) => (
  <div className="sports-tab-content">
    <p className={`sports-large-text ${props.classes.join(' ')}`}>
      {props.text}
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: thganks for your reply...each div will have different content...will it work that time...I am confused...can you update in my fiddle

Comment: Can you put more concrete examples of how your state will change? This is pretty abstract. You can basically update the `state.panes[<index>].<property>` and the change will be reflected in the render

Comment: for first day it will have some text in div, after three days when they come back to that div...it  will show another content

Comment: can you help me with one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776856/remove-css-class-when-we-switch-tab-from-li-tag